# Having issue with executing a Python file, I think it may be a directory problem?

Tags: python

I'm trying to execute a file (Test_UnitTesting.py) that I've wrote to test another file (UnitTesting.py).

It's fairly simple:

UnitTesting.py

```
def square(number):
    return number ** 2
```

Test_UnitTesting.py

```
import unittest

from UnitTesting import square

class TestSquare(unittest.TestCase): 
    def test1(self): 
        self.assertEqual(square(2), 4) # test when 2 is given as input the output is 4.
        self.assertEqual(square(3.0), 9.0)  # test when 3.0 is given as input the output is 9.0.
        self.assertNotEqual(square(-3), -9)  # test when -3 is given as input the output is not -9.
```

I'm using Powershell to execute the code using the following:

```
Python Test_UnitTesting.py
```

I'm expecting it to return whether the test had failed or not but I'm seeing nothing in the terminal.

It's also important to note that in the "Test_UnitTesting.py", it does not recognise "UnitTesting".

Can anyone help?

Comment: `Python Test_UnitTesting.py` does not execute the testcase, at least you need `unittest.main()`.

Comment: Is "UnitTesting.py" in your python path?

Comment: "It's also important to note that in the "Test_UnitTesting.py", it does not recognise "UnitTesting"."

What does that mean, precisely?